# What to do when OP copies and improves my answer?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

In the question **[Insert Image (from URL) from Google Sheet Cell to Google Doc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19818344/insert-image-from-url-from-google-sheet-cell-to-google-doc/19822815#19822815)**, OP posted an answer that extends mine. He even thanked me early in the answer.

I don't disagree that the OP response is more complete than mine, but I thought it was rude to not give me the correct answer checkmark.

What's the etiquete in this case? Should I ask him to approve my answer?

He doesn't have karma enough to edit my question with his comments.

Comment: If the user takes, your answer and improves it; it is best practice for him to create his own answer and accept it. This will allow future users to see what actually worked for the op. However, if he did find your answer helpful and used part of it, he should at least give you an upvote IMHO.

Comment: I've done this myself, where an answer gives me a nudge in the right direction. In this case I can understand how you feel, since all OP did was wrap your answer in a `for` loop, but there's not much you can do about this.

Comment: Lots of talk about "karma" today

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't have to do anything really. If the answer the OP wrote is what he ultimately ended up doing (thereby answering his question) he is free to accept it.

Yes, he based it on your contribution, so he should clearly credit you. And that he did (though I've gone in and linked directly to your answer, among other edits). An upvote might have been nice (and I would have given it in such a situation), but is not mandatory and was not possible for the OP due to his reputation at the time.

So just let it go. Don't go nag him to approve your answer.

Comment: To be fair, the asker did not have enough rep to upvote the answer by eduardo.

Comment: Ah true, I keep forgetting that @MatthiasBauch. I updated my answer accordingly. Thanks.